# some clarification for the below program

Tags: c++, pointers, char, int

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


char* function1()
{
    char* var = new char;
    var[0] = 'q';
    var[1] = 'p';
    return var;
}


int* function2()
{
    int* var = new int;
    var[0] = 12;
    var[1] = 20;
    return var;
}


int main() {

    cout << function1() << endl;
    cout << function2() << endl;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
qp
0x9cf9018
```

There are some doubts in this program. Any discussion will be very helpful to understand the things.

```
 1. char* var = new char;
```

As per my understanding so far, this statement says: Give me the address of a memory location where i can store a character. so compiler will allocate one byte of memory. 
Then why we are able to store any number of characters as:

```
var[0] = 'q';
var[1] = 'p';
var[1] = 'r';
```

If the answer is because of contiguous memory location, we can access next memory, then  are we not accessing something which is not given to us. and also unknowingly overwriting the things, which belongs to others. If answer is again YES, then why compiler allowing us to do this. and how to avoid this thing.  Also if we are not avoiding this thing, can we get some unexpected results in multiple run of the program?

```
2. The answered behavior of above point is same for int* var = new int; and char* var = new char, or is different. And if is different, what is the difference?

3. why one cout is printing value, while other printing address?
```

Comment: function1 writes past the end of the allocated space. function2 as well

Comment: Each of those functions exhibit **undefined behavior**. You're accessing (and in this case, writing-to) memory outside your allocation range.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 char* var = new char;

Your understanding is correct. Code is forcefully trying to insert characters at other location, which invoke UB (**undefined behavior**)

> 2 The answered behavior of above ...

See above

> 3 why one cout is printing value, while other printing address?

Again UB, for first you're *unlucky* to get expected output

Answer (score 0):

Since questions 1 and 2 are already answered by P0W, the answer to question 3 is that when you pass a pointer to a null terminated string to cout, it prints the string.

Comment: Thanks for response. But here i am not passing pointer to string. Its Pointer to char. Also if  compiler is assuming it string, who and how NULL is getting appended to it??

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal _"who & how NULL .."_ Its UB, no justification can be given. As I told you were _unlucky_ to get that result. Normally it should just display q with some garbage values, until it finds a null character, some where in memory

Comment: pointer to a string == pointer to the first element of an array of chars. and as P0W pointed out, you got lucky as there was a null char after qp. usually the behavior is undefined. sometime it will print garbage and most of the times will cause a crash with segmentation fault. And most of the times, heap corruptions will lead to completely strange behavior, like process taking up too large space or just crashing. these types of things are very hard to debug and usually result in debugging nightmares.